# ListView selected position on selection in ASP

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, listview

I have a Listview ItemList that has a relatively small height attribute. Therefore it scrolls after around 3 items. If I scroll through the List and select an item the list reloads and goes to the top. I would like the selected item to show after selected and also highlighted. How can I do this? I have the following:

```
<asp:Content ID="" runat="server">
....
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ListUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:ListView ID="ListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="aDataSource" DataKeyNames="key">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton_Click">
                 ....ITEMS....
            </asp:LinkButton>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:ListView>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Below is another UpdatePanel with all kinds of labels and textboxes and such.

Is there anything I can put in the codebehind to keep the position of the items after one has been selected?

Comment: Please show your ListView markup (I don't think the one shown in your question matches the one you're describing).